# Prevent Scrolling when Keyboard open

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

I am creating a Simple Example in Windows phone 8.1 where I am having an issue related with UI.

I have a grid which contains an image in the header and a textbox below:

```
 <Grid>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Image Source="Assets/topbar.png" />

    <TextBox Grid.Row="1"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

</Grid>
```

The problem is that when the textbox gets focus, the header image is displayed at the top of the screen, but I need the header image to remain at the same place while the textbox gets focus.

Please share any ideas for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take Grid layout with 3 rows for Header, Body, Footer. Like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0"> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" /> 
        <RowDefinition /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" /> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Name="Header" Background="#FF1DA8D1"> 
        <TextBlock Text="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" /> 
    </StackPanel> 

    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Background="Orange" Name="Body"> 
       <Grid > 
            <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
                <RowDefinition Height="auto" />  
            </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Name="txtMessage" 
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" 
                    AcceptsReturn="True" 
                    TextChanged="txtMessage_TextChanged" 
                    GotFocus="txtMessage_GotFocus" 
                    LostFocus="txtMessage_LostFocus" 
                    Tap="txtMessage_Tap" /> 
     </Grid> 
     </ScrollViewer> 

    <Grid Grid.Row="2" Name="FooterPlaceholder" Visibility="Collapsed"/> 
    <StackPanel Name="withoutkeyboardfooter"  Grid.Row="2" Background="#FF1DA8D1"> 
        <TextBlock  Text="Footer" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="40" /> 
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In Above xaml code main part is Body(Grid.Row=1) content which is having scrollviewer with a TextBox for testing purpose.So that here the TextBox is having following events to handle keyboard issue.

TextChanged="txtMessage_TextChanged"

GotFocus="txtMessage_GotFocus"

LostFocus="txtMessage_LostFocus"

Tap="txtMessage_Tap"

Here we need to use these events for manually specifying the scroll positions. Generally on initially tapping a populated Textbox, scrolling to the point at which the user wants the cursor to be specifically to an area that would be hidden after the keyboard is shown requires some manual means to accomplish. This is handled on the **Tap** event.

```
double tapOffset; 
private void txtMessage_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input. 
GestureEventArgs e) 

{ 
   tapOffset = e.GetPosition(txtMessage).Y - 80; 
}
```

The keyboard height differs between different resolutions, so some checking is required to find the correct keyboard height, which can be done on the page’s **Loaded** event.

```
void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
var deviceWidth = this.ActualWidth;  

var isHdDevice = (deviceWidth > 500 ? true : false); 

  if (isHdDevice) 

            keyboardHeight = 540; 
        else 
            keyboardHeight = 336; 

 //this will be used to offset other controls on the page into the viewable area 
FooterPlaceholder.Height = keyboardHeight; 
}
```

And we need to do like this  at LostFocus  Event :

```
private void txtMessage_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    { 
        //hide the keyboard placeholder from screen 
        //allowing the scrollviewer to re-occupy the available area again 
        this.FooterPlaceholder.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 
        withoutkeyboardfooter.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; 
        footerkeyboard.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; 

    }
```